# Curvature and Parametrization of the Pacman Curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves, curvature, geodesic

I'm trying to find the Geodesic curvature of the circle $u = u_0$ for the circular cone with a vertex angle of $2ϕ$ that is parametrized by $ x(u,v)=(utanϕcosv,utanϕsinv,u)$ for $0≤u≤u0$ and $0≤v≤2π.$ The Equation for Geodesic curvature is $k_g = kN(n \times T)$ which I found to be $k_g = \frac{\cos \phi}{u_0}$. Now I want to show that this is the same as the curvature of the curve we get when we open up the cone. Like this: 
[image]

And the textbook I'm using says the parametrization for the pacman region is $x(u,v) = (u\cos v, u\sin v, 0)$ for $0 \leq u \leq R, 0 \leq v \leq V$ where $V$ is less than $2 \pi$. Now I'm not sure how to parametrize the pacman curve. I thought you would take $u = u_0$ and then compute the curvature but I don't think that is right. I'm not sure how to compute the curvature of the curve that is identical to the circle at the bottom of the cone once opened.

Comment: You don't need a parametrization (although you get it by taking $u=R$ there, $0\le v\le V$. The key thing is to relate the radius and angle of pacman to $u_0$ and $\phi$. What lengths in the picture match up? Do the work.

Comment: So I take it that the angle of the pacman is $2 \phi$ and the radius is $u_0$. I'm just not sure how you can relate these I was under the impression you could parametrize the pacman curve then find it's curvature.

Comment: But then even if you have the radius and angle how would you go from there to find the curvature?

Comment: How do you find the curvature of a circle?

Comment: So you need to use $u_0$ and $2 \phi$ to create a parametrization of a circle. Normally parametrize $a(t) = (u_0 \cos t, u_0 \sin t, 0)$ but where does the $2 \phi$ come in.

Comment: Do you not just *know* the curvature of a circle of radius $R$? As I said, you have to relate $R$ to $u_0$ and $\phi$ using geometry.

Comment: Yes, the curvature is $\frac{1}{R}$ so I am assuming that curvature of our new circle is $ \frac{1}{u_0} $ however I am just confused on how to relate $\phi$ other than $2\phi$ being the angle between the two endpoints of our curve.

Comment: You should figure this out for yourself. You need to match the dimensions of pacman to the dimensions of the cone (the slant height and the circumference).